# Calculate subtotal and total price depending on selected options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at jquery and probably my script is not well coded, but I'm making an online cinema project for College and don't know what's wrong with my booking system. Effectively, I have got a table with  type of ticket, price and quantity, and I want to update the subtotal and total price depending on user's selection.
Unfortunately, I have researched other answers here and some tutorials but none of them work for me.
This is my html table:

```
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ticket</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">Subtotal</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td id="total"><span>TOTAL</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Adult</td>
        <td><span id="price" class="price">£8.25</span></td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" id="qty" name="qty">
             <option value="0">0</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             <option value="6">6</option>
             <option value="7">7</option>
             <option value="8">8</option>
             <option value="9">9</option>
          </select>  
        </td>
        <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">£0</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Junior</td>
        <td><span id="price" class="price">£6.75</span></td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="qty">
             <option value="0">0</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             <option value="6">6</option>
             <option value="7">7</option>
             <option value="8">8</option>
             <option value="9">9</option>
          </select> 
        </td>
        <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">£0</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Senior</td>
        <td><span id="price" class="price">£6.75</span></td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="qty">
             <option value="0">0</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             <option value="6">6</option>
             <option value="7">7</option>
             <option value="8">8</option>
             <option value="9">9</option>
          </select> 
        </td>
        <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">£0</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Student</td>
        <td><span id="price" class="price">£6.75</span> </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="qty">
             <option value="0">0</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
             <option value="5">5</option>
             <option value="6">6</option>
             <option value="7">7</option>
             <option value="8">8</option>
             <option value="9">9</option>
          </select> 
        </td>
        <td><span id="subtotal" class="subtotal">£0</span></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

And this is my js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    update_amounts();
    $('.qty').change(function () {
        update_amounts();
    });
});

function update_amounts()
{
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = (qty*price)
        sum+=amount;
        $(this).find('.subtotal').text(''+amount);
    });

    //just update the total to sum  
    $('.total').text(sum);
}
```

It would be great if anyone could help me.
Thank you really much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/4hrx38nf/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    update_amounts();
    // Fix: Invalid selector for the select fields
    $('select[name=qty]').change(update_amounts);
});

function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // Fix: price is in text, not in a form field
        // and it must be cleaned from the pound sign
        var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');
        var amount = (qty * price);
        sum += amount;
        $(this).find('.subtotal').text('£' + amount);
    });

    //just update the total to sum  
    $('.total').text('£' + sum);
}
```

I also did a HTML fix in `tfoot`:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td><span>TOTAL</span></td>
        <!-- Fix: Moved the total field to the right place -->
        <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

So now it works, but there are still a couple of problems. `id` attributes must be unique, there are multiple of `price` and `subtotal`. I suggest removing them.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solved the problem for you.